# Unable to run webapp after adding filter and llistner of spring security in web.xml of spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having spring mvc project where i'm trying to add spring security   but after adding spring security filters and listner project stop working and if i'm remove listner then when i enter the url i have to secure it ask me for add listner.

here my web.xml

```
    <web-app version="2.5"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <!--
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>-->
        <!--<listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>-->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/*.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Spring-security.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

        <http auto-config="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
            <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="j_spring_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/login"/>
            <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
        </http>

        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <authentication-provider ref="AuthenticationProvider"/>
        </authentication-manager>

        <beans:bean id="AuthenticationProvider" class="com.javatpoint"></beans:bean>

    </beans:beans>
```

error i'm getting

[image]

could you please suggest me what i'm doing wrong in this configuration

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Comment: but when add Listener then it stop working

Comment: share full stacttrace of exception in question

Comment: <!--<listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>-->    uncomment ContextLoaderLister from web.xml

Comment: when i uncomment it app stop working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146134/discussion-between-vaibs-and-abhijeet-gulve).